# Including HTML inside Jekyll tag

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

Instead of writing out `{% include link_to.html i=5 text="hello world" %}` all the time, I've written a custom tag that allows me to do `{% link_to 5 hello world %}`. It finds the page with data `i` equal to 5 and creates a link to it.

But it feels clunky to generate HTML strings from inside the tag code, and it is awkward to write complicated code logic inside the HTML include code. So  is there a way to have the tag definition do the heavy lifting of finding the relevant page to link to, and have it pass on what it found to `link_to.html` to render? Sort of like the controller passing information on to the view in Rails.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something related [here](http://cheat.jekyll.tips/) or try asking on [Jekyll Talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/).

Comment: You seem to be asking us to refactor custom tag code that we cannot see. Could you paste the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript.accessObject(ObjectName, Location).reason(NumberOfColumns);
API.Go.javascript.Obj = new Runtime(4); // how many seconds we want the page to take when loading.
```

Comment: Wow, thinking way ahead... you don't see that often nowdays ;)

Lucky, because now ironically they both are offline!

Comment: @Booligoosh Yeah nowadays you don't see too many people thinking ahead. I hope the code works. It may be a bit outdated but I'm sure you can edit the code a little bit to make it work.